# dependsOnMethods annotation throws java.io.IOException, which is not annotated with @Test or not included

Tags: java, annotations, testng

I am getting exception : 
    throws java.io.IOException, which is not annotated with @Test or not included.

when using `@Test(dependsOnMethods=..)`

I have two methods like this :

```
@Test(dependsOnMethods=.."xyz")
public void abc() throws IOException(){
 //some operation
}

@Test
public void xyz() throws IOException(){
 //some operation
}

Exception is :
Caused by:
```

> org.testng.TestNGException: 
>       abc() is depending on method public void xyz() throws java.io.IOException, which is not annotated with @Test or not
>   included.

I have tried with expectedExceptions annotation but still the exception occur. Can someone suggest how to handle it.

Comment: Add `@Test` to xyz? Or remove the dependsOnMethod if it's (xyz is) not to be tested discretely.

Comment: adding @Test to xyz is also throwing same exception.

Comment: Do you run the class containing these tests directly or TestNg suite containing included method?
You need to include both methods dependent and dependable if you use *.xml suite file.

Comment: I am running using xml file. Xml file will contains all classes inside the package and will run it.  Is there any specific way to specify dependsOnMethods relation in xml file. if yes please let me know

Comment: @Priti, If you run the whole class you don't need to add anything, it should work. Also, are you sure that there is no other xyz() method? Let's say in you test parent class, if any.

Comment: Also faced the same issue, and only workaround I could see to get it work is to have both the test in same group and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [user1058106](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058106/user1058106):

> Do you run the class containing these tests directly or TestNg suite containing
> included method? You need to include both methods dependent and
> dependable if you use *.xml suite file.

You need to update your XML file to something like:

```xml
<test name="someName">
    <classes>
        <class name="yourClassName">
            <methods>
                <include name="xyz" />
                <include name="abc" />
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
```